# Create Fake Entry in sysfs

Tags: linux

I'm targeting a program that tries to open a file in /sys that doesn't exist. Is there a way to create that file so the program continues? (Normally you can't create flies in sysfs.)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating a file, you can hook the open/read functions in the binary and make them return the data it needs. For example, using `LD_PRELOAD`:

https://github.com/poliva/ldpreloadhook